# Error: Cannot read property of null

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**CODE:**

```
var Game = createReactClass({

    getInitalState() {
        return {
            start: false
        }                    
    },

    handleStartClick() {
        this.setState({
            start: true
        })
    },

    handleStopClick() {
        this.setState({
            start: false
        })
    },

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>React.js Game of Life</h1>
                <div className="buttons">
                    <button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={this.handelStopClick}>Stop</button>
                    <button className="btn btn-success" onClick={this.handelStartClick}>Start</button>
                </div>
                <Board start={this.state.start}/>
            </div>
        )
    }

});
```

---

**QUESTION:**

Here is the error I get:

> Cannot read property 'start' of null

If I change `this.state.start` to `this.props.start`, the error goes away but the board does not `render`.

How can I resolve this situation ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue is, you have a spelling mistake, Instead of `getInitalState` use `getInitialState`, that's why, you are getting that error:

> Cannot read property 'start' of null

Use this, it will work:

```
getInitialState() {
    return {
        start: false
    }                    
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Your state object is null. This is because you have typo in your function name. The function name should be `getInitialState`. Then your state would have the default value of `start:false`